# Select individual value in addition to range in group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like this

```
   id   | job_id   | measurement_id   |      value       | timestamp
--------+----------+------------------+------------------+-----------
      1 | myJobId  | myMeasurementId  | 55.6111297607422 |    49212
      2 | myJobId  | myMeasurementId  | 55.6607780456543 |    49412
```

I'd like to get the max value in certain time ranges, however I also need the timestamp associated with the individual measurement.

```
  range   |         max         |     timestamp
----------+---------------------+------------------
        0 | 68.7833782357044665 |       20535552
   377613 | 67.9283221509389440 |       20535552
   755226 | 67.2932168855194184 |       20535552
```

I tried the following statement but run into an error

```
select (timestamp/377613)*377613 as range, max(value), timestamp
from measurements
where job_id = 'myJobId' and measurement_id = 'myMeasurementId'
group by timestamp/377613
order by 1;


ERROR:  column "measurements.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Without the second timestamp the statement works well but doesnt deliver the timestamp associated with the max value of course. How can I get that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select (timestamp/377613)*377613 as range, value, timestamp,
       row_number() over(partition by (timestamp/377613)*377613 order by value desc) as rn
from measurements
where job_id = 'myJobId' and measurement_id = 'myMeasurementId'
)A when rn=1
```

Comment: I can't edit the post because edits need to be at leas 6 characters long. "when" should be "where" and the closing parentheses after "timestamp/377613" shopuld not be there

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you should use `distinct on` for this operation.  For convenience, you can also calculate the range using a lateral join:

```
select distinct on (v.range) v.range, m.value), m.timestamp
from measurements m cross join lateral
     (values (m.timestamp/377613) * 377613)) as range
where m.job_id = 'myJobId' and m.measurement_id = 'myMeasurementId'
order by v.range, m.timestamp;
```

`distinct on` is a Postgres extension -- but one that happens to be quite helpful.  It sorts the data and chooses the first row that it encounters for each value in the `distinct on` clause.

In general, `distinct on` is faster than the corresponding query using window functions.